# why can't i __init__ my custom FancyURLopener with the user & passwd

Tags: python, urllib

I'm unable to write a custom urllib.FancyURLopener which initializes the user and passwd values in the constructor.  I can get it to work fine with an empty constructor and a subsequent call to setpasswd.  When I try to set the user and password in the constructor, I get strange errors regarding a missing attribute 'tempcache'.  Am I missing some Python syntax/usage regarding **init**?

I want to be able to specify my user and passwd in the constructor like so:

```
opener = MyRouterOpener("", "secretPassword")
page = opener.open("http://192.168.1.1/Status_Router.asp")
#do something with the page
```

Trying this way fails:

```
import urllib

class MyRouterOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    def __init__(self, user, passwd):
        self.setpasswd(user, passwd)

    def setpasswd(self, user, passwd):
        self.__user = user
        self.__passwd = passwd

    def prompt_user_passwd(self, host, realm):
        return self.__user, self.__passwd

opener = MyRouterOpener("", "secretPassword")
statusPage = opener.open("http://192.168.1.1/Status_Router.asp")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\Desktop\DynDns.enom.bad.py", line 15, in <module>
    statusPage = opener.open("http://192.168.1.1/Status_Router.asp")
  File "C:\Users\pengt\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 179, in open
    if self.tempcache and fullurl in self.tempcache:
AttributeError: RouterOpener instance has no attribute 'tempcache'
Exception AttributeError: "RouterOpener instance has no attribute 'tempcache'" in <bound method RouterOpener.__del__ of <__main__.RouterOpener instance at 0x022AB9E0>> ignored
```

I've also tried:

```
import urllib

class RouterOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
def __init__(self, user, passwd):
    self.__user = user
    self.__passwd = passwd

def prompt_user_passwd(self, host, realm):
    return self.__user, self.__passwd

opener = RouterOpener("", "secretPassword")
statusPage = opener.open("http://192.168.1.1/Status_Router.asp")
```

But this produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\Desktop\DynDns.enom.bad.py", line 12, in <module>
    statusPage = opener.open("http://192.168.1.1/Status_Router.asp")
  File "C:\Users\pengt\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 179, in open
    if self.tempcache and fullurl in self.tempcache:
AttributeError: RouterOpener instance has no attribute 'tempcache'
Exception AttributeError: "RouterOpener instance has no attribute 'tempcache'" in <bound method RouterOpener.__del__ of <__main__.RouterOpener instance at 0x0231B968>> ignored
```

The only thing I've been able to get work is:

```
import urllib

class MyRouterOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    def setpasswd(self, user, passwd):
        self.__user = user
        self.__passwd = passwd

    def prompt_user_passwd(self, host, realm):
        return self.__user, self.__passwd

opener = MyRouterOpener()
opener.setpasswd("", "secretPassword")
statusPage = opener.open("http://192.168.1.1/Status_Router.asp")
```

But then I'm specifying my user and passwd on a separate line.  I know this is no big deal really, but like I say above I'm really wanting to know if I'm missing something about Python regarding inheritance and **init** etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have to call the parent object's **init** which sets the tempcache attribute.

```
def __init__(self, user, passwd):
    self.__user = user
    self.__passwd = passwd
    urllib.FancyURLopener.__init__(self)
```

(Call it with the proper arguments for the urllib.FancyURLopener creator)

Comment: For some reason the code just stopped working for me. If you get a TypeError exception, use the following instead:

urllib.FancyURLopener.__init__(self)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, forgot how to use super. Use the code in the first comment: urllib.FancyURLopener.__init__(self)

Comment: I will mark this correct if you change the super(... line to urllib.FancyURLopener.__init__(self) which I've verified actually works.

Is inheritance/constructor chaining not commonly used in python?  Is that why people seem to have such trouble with this?

Comment: [This should have been the second comment]gives me: Traceback (most recent call last): File "W:\Desktop\DynDns.enom.bad.py", line 12, in <module> opener = MyRouterOpener("", "secretPassword") File "W:\Desktop\DynDns.enom.bad.py", line 7, in init super( urllib.FancyURLopener, self ).__init__() TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj Exception AttributeError: "MyRouterOpener instance has no attribute 'tempcache'" in <bound method MyRouterOpener.__del__ of <__main__.MyRouterOpener instance at 0x022CB990>> ignored

Comment: Done. Yeah Python doesn't support it. You have to call it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call the superclass' `__init__` method, like so:

```
class MyRouterOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    def __init__(self, user, passwd):
        # grr, old-style classes. :(
        urllib.FancyURLopener.__init__(self)

        # fancy custom fun stuff!
        self.__user = user
        self.__passwd = passwd
```

Comment: gives me Traceback (most recent call last): File "W:\Desktop\DynDns.enom.bad.py", line 12, in <module> opener = MyRouterOpener("", "secretPassword") File "W:\Desktop\DynDns.enom.bad.py", line 5, in init super(MyRouterOpener, self).__init__() TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj Exception AttributeError: "MyRouterOpener instance has no attribute 'tempcache'" in <bound method MyRouterOpener.__del__ of <__main__.MyRouterOpener instance at 0x0225B9B8>> ignored

Comment: Doh. Apparently it's an "old-style class" (long story). My edited code will work.

Comment: Although it looks like that's already been covered, so my answer was superfluous. Which is fine. :)